# PostgreSQL Db traffic encryption with Django

Tags: django, postgresql, encryption

I am using Django 3.08 with a PostgreSQL 12 Remote server. I have searched the docs for Postgres and Django, but can’t find discussion of how/if Django encrypts the traffic between my app and the dB.

It looks like to me that the traffic is encrypted using md5 encryption by default in PostgreSQL based on the settings in PostgreSQL,and sends it by tcp over port 5432. It is my understanding that md5 is no longer sufficient encryption. However PostgreSQL has supported scram-Sha-256 since PostgreSQL 10. Does anyone know or have a reference to where I can set my app to use the stronger encryption or is it all taken care of if I set all traffic on my site to use https in the settings.py file. Or, will Django use scram-Sha-256 if I just change the setting in PostgreSQL?

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption scheme, as you can't retrieve the data. As far as I'm aware, PostgreSQL normally uses MD5 to store password hashes. You also mention scram-sha-256, which is also meant for hashing passwords, not encrypt data.


If you want to encrypt the data that is transiting in the network, you need to connect to Postgres over SSL. For more information, look at this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ssl-tcp.html


Also, your https configuration for Django is likely only for requests that Django is serving. Postgres doesn't talk to it's clients via https.

Answer (score 0):

md5 and scram-sha-256 are for password-based authentication, not for encryption.  While the password exchange itself would not be readable in clear text to someone eavesdropping on the connection, the rest of the data (queries and results) still would be readable, and changeable if the session is hijacked.

Encryption is implemented by ssl (common), or in recent versions perhaps by encryption tied to GSSAPI authentication (which I think is rare).

The reference of course would be [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html) for the server and [the client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html) (Django as far as I know uses psycopg2, which in turn uses libpq)